# Shared ownership of a resource without dynamic memory allocation

Tags: rust, dynamic-memory-allocation, ownership

I am working with resources whose creation and destruction are modelled by the following functions:

```rust
/// Creates a resource and returns a handle to it
unsafe fn create_resource() -> i32 {
    println!("Resource creation!");
    0
}

/// Destroy the resource corresponding to the given handle
unsafe fn destroy_resource(handle: i32) {
    println!("Resource destruction!");
}
```

I wrap a resource handle in a struct to take advantage of OBRM:

```rust
struct Resource {
    handle: i32
}

impl Resource {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            handle: unsafe { create_resource() },
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Resource {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            destroy_resource(self.handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes shared ownership is desirable, so I can use a reference-counting smart pointer containing a `Resource` object, e. g. `Arc<Resource>`. As far as I know, `Rc` and `Arc` allocate their contained value on the heap. This is not actually needed here: an alternative could simply keep track of a reference count and a resource handle. Does such a smart pointer already exist, and if not, what would be the simplest way to implement it?

(I don't actually need to optimize the dynamic memory allocations away for a project, this is out of sheer curiosity)

Comment: `Rc` and `Arc` don't only store the contained value on the heap, but also the reference count itself. The count can't be stored on the independent handles, so unless you have a shared-ownership mechanism that avoids that problem (like being stored on the resource itself), I don't see a way. The only other options for storage are static and local variables. Static storage *could* be done, but depends on your use-case having a non-dynamic number of handles. And for local variable storage, you'd be better off just using a reference.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to make such a smart pointer — that takes a single-ownership resource and creates a reference-counted resource — *generically,* without allocation. The key fact is that **the reference count must be stored somewhere.** Places it could be stored:

- Like `Rc` does, in a heap allocation all the pointers point to: allocates (and is basically just `Rc`).
- In a field inside the shared pointer: doesn't work because different clones of the shared pointer must agree upon what the reference count is.
- In a field inside the resource: now the resource has to store the count in an interior mutable fashion, so there's almost no work being saved versus having a fully custom refcounted pointer.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the last bullet point is usually called _intrusive reference-counting_ and it was popularized in other languages to overcome shortcomings that aren't present in Rust.  Therefore it doesn't actually solve any real problem in Rust, and non-intrusive reference counting via `Rc`/`Arc` is the way to go here.

Comment: Is it possible to only allocate memory for the reference count then, but to keep the handle or a "shallow" copy of the `Resource` wrapper as a field?

Comment: @Debaug Sure, you could do that. The only advantage over Rc would be avoiding the memory read of following the Rc pointer to get to the handle, though.